XCode 15.4 keeps crashing when trying to "Record UI Tests"
I'm using Xcode Version 15.4 (15F31d) and when I click the Record UI Tests icon, as soon as it finishes building, Xcode crashes. I'm not 100% sure why this is happening, but I've seen multiple bug reports about this issue. I'm fine with writing the UI Tests manually but seems like a good feature.
I've tried deleting the derived data folder, rebuilding the whole app, starting the app and then clicking the "Record UI Tests" but nothing seems to work?
Is there a fix of this issue or is it deprecated? Are there any alternative options I can use that achieve the same sort of features as it is very handy to not have to write the button clicks and navigation by hand.
After clicking on the button, it builds and then throws a crash log
https://pastebin.com/uNPjqrGH
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------
 
Process:               Xcode [9074]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               15.4 (22622)
Build Info:            IDEApplication-22622000000000000~2 (15F31d)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       865623187
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501
 
Date/Time:             2024-08-26 05:15:59.2341 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 14.3.1 (23D60)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     8.3 (21P3049)
Anonymous UUID:        DBF8F146-5FA3-D8CE-36F3-E2CFEC188FC1
 
 
Time Awake Since Boot: 1600000 seconds
 
System Integrity Protection: enabled
 
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
 
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
 
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   Xcode [9074]


What are we supposed to do about this? You should be filing a bug with Apple if Xcode is crashing. Also be sure to try out the latest Xcode 16 beta, just on the offchance that the crash has been fixed already there.
