Xcode 15/16 crashes immediately when trying to use XCUITest UI recorder on iOS 17/18 device
I am trying to use the XCUITest UIrecorder for some UI tests where having the button identifier isn't enough. But soon as I hit record in Xcode UI test it (Xcode) crashes immediately, if the app is running on an iOS 17 or 18 physical device. iOS 16 devices do work, also works in the simulator.
Our app uses a lot of metal views, so most of the testing needs to be done on a physical device. I've tried clearing the derived data folder. Also this fails with a clean install and an effectively blank new project. UI Automation has been enabled in device settings. So there shouldn't be any conflicts. Any work arounds?

I'd say much the same that I said on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78914815/xcode-15-4-keeps-crashing-when-trying-to-record-ui-tests — it's Apple that you should be talking to about this, not Stack Overflow.

@matt This has been filed with Apple as well. But people also ask questions about set up on SO. Thanks

It might be helpful to the community if you would supply your feedback ID as part of the question.

Sure thing: FB15355481
